# Node terminal animation is not working (it's only showing the first two items in the array)

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, command-line-interface

I am trying to create a terminal animation for a CLI about food. While one of my requests is being made, I wanted to run a loading animation until the promise is resolved. The animation is composed of two arrays, one representing a person opening and closing their mouth and the other is the "sandwich" (a bunch of equals signs) that is to be eaten. See below.

```
var face = [":D", ":|"];
var sandwich = ['======', '=====', '====', '===', '==', '='];
```

I am using `setInterval` to increment the values of x and y (which represent the indexes of their respective arrays) until they reach a threshold. For `face` that threshold is 1 (since first index is 0) and for `sandwich` it is 5.

What I want to happen is as the values of x/y are incremented, the next item in their respective arrays is written out to the console. See the code below.

```
const muncher = () =>{
    var face = [":D", ":|"];
    var sandwich = ['======', '=====', '====', '===', '==', '='];
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    return setInterval(() => {
        process.stdout.write("\r" + face[x++] + sandwich[y++]);
        x &= 1;
        y &= 5;
    }, 250);
};
```

Once `y` is 5 and `x` is 1, they should go back to 0 and start the incrementing over again. Rather than the sandwich becoming less and less each time (`======`... `=====`... `====`... etc) but it appears both arrays just toggle between the first and second element. For `sandwich` it looks like this: `======` and `=====`. I also tried making the arrays of equal length and having `x` and `y` be the same number but it still isn't working.

My problem is occurring within node but I adapted it to browser JS in the snippet to better illustrate my issue.

```js
var targ = document.getElementById('muncher');
const muncher = () => {
    var face = [":D", ":|"];
    //also tried var face = [":D", ":|", ":/", ":o", ":D", ":|"];
    var sandwich = ['======', '=====', '====', '===', '==', '='];
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    return setInterval(() => {
        targ.innerText = "\r" + face[x++] + sandwich[y++];
        x &= 1;
        // also tried x&= 5 when face is the same length as sandwich
        y &= 5;
    }, 250);
};

muncher()
```

```html
<div id='muncher'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problme is the bitwise operator which is changing the value of x and y to 0 and 1 respectively. Something like this should work

```js
var targ = document.getElementById('muncher');
const muncher = () => {
    var face = [":D", ":|"];
    //also tried var face = [":D", ":|", ":/", ":o", ":D", ":|"];
    var sandwich = ['======', '=====', '====', '===', '==', '='];
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    return setInterval(() => {
        targ.innerText = "\r" + face[x++] + sandwich[y++];
        x = x > 1 ? 0 : x;
        y = y > 5 ? 0 : y;
    }, 250);
};

muncher()
```

```html
<div id="muncher"/>
```

Comment: I ran into an issue (with `stdout.write()` not with your above code) where the cursor was moving in the terminal but the characters weren't updating. All I had to do was add `process.stdout.clearLine();` as the first line within the `setInterval` and along with your solution it works now. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As a second option, you can try this package I've created:

https://github.com/ErAz7/Termination

First install the package (`npm i termination` or `yarn add termination`), then with this code you can achieve what you want (with a better animation loop):

[SEE DEMO HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8saP.gif)

```js
const { Animation } = require('termination');

const personFrames = [':|', ':D'];

const createObject = (x, y, content, color) => animation.add({
    x: x,
    y: y,
    content: content,
    replaceSpace: true,
    color: color,
});

const animation = new Animation({
    maxSize: {
        width: 10,
        height: 1,
    },
});

const sandwich = createObject(8, 0, '======', 'yellow');
const person = createObject(0, 0, personFrames[0], 'green');

const personFramesTransition = person.transition([
    {
        props: { content: personFrames[1] },
        duration: 100
    }
], { loop: true, alternate: true });

const sandwichMoveTransition = sandwich.transition([
    {
        props: { x: -8, y: 0 },
        func: 'linear',
        duration: 1400
    }
], { loop: true, loopInterval: 100 });

animation.start();

personFramesTransition.run();
sandwichMoveTransition.run();
```

This is a little longer but offers much more control over animation properties.

the package supports

- **promise based tranition**
- **easing transition functions**
- **looped transition**
- **frame rate control**
- **playback speed control**
- **canvas size options**
- **colors**

and some other useful features to create animations on terminal

Comment: Please [disclose your affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) when advertising your own product. Also, you have to answer the question, not just list features.

Comment: @LucaKiebel please check again